# To check application status or not

Tags: powershell

I have a application, I am trying to check the task is successful completed or not.

I am trying to collect the event message from the events, which state as completed.

Code:

```
$app1 = "###########" # application name
$sourcelocation = "$$$$$$$$$" # from location
$Destination = "@@@@@@@@@@@@"
$events = Get-SECEvent -MaxSamples 100 -Start (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1) 
if ($event.Message -match "Moving of application $app1 * completed") {
    Write-Host "The application is completed"
} else {
    Write-Host "The application is Not completed"
}
```

The below is the message event looks like.

```
Message : Moving of application "###########" from "$$$$$$$$$", &&&&&&&&&&& to 
                       @@@@@@@@@@@@, &&&&&&&&&&& completed
```

Note: In the Message event, I can see other applications information too, but I want this particular `$app1`, `$source` location and `$Destination` identified and completed.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't look like a [mcve]

Comment: what is `Get-SECEvent`? i cannot find any info on it at all ... [*frown*]

Comment: You are not even using any of the additional identifying data points as part of your checks, so, by design, it's going to grab anything that matches that string you passed. If you want something specific, then you have pass something specific, using all needed attributes. @LeeDaily, that Get-SECEvent is apparently and wrapper thing they are doing inside their org. As you noted, it is nowhere on any of the trusted / semi-trusted repos online.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. Get-SECEvent is internal customized module, i am looking help to check the reg expression to match the wording/lines in if statement with the message event displayed.So that i can check application is completed or not.